# Not able to download excel file using PHPExcel from angular

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am using the following code snippet to create the excel file, which works fine. I have created a view in PHP that asks for data and the controller returns the excel with the data but when I am making a HTTP call (`POST` since I need to send some data) from my angular code, the PHP web service instead of the file returns some ASCII code in response.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$filename='FILE'.date("d-m-Y").'.xls';

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($ci->excel, 'Excel5');  
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I have tried other things like `ob_end_clean()`, `exit;` after `save()` method, replacing `Content-Type` with `MIME-Type` but nothing works for me. Do I need to add something to my angular code?

Comment: That "ASCII code" is likely to be the actual binary stream of data for the Excel file.... if you're calling this routine through Ajax, then you need to set angular to handle it correctly

Comment: @MarkBaker

ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿþÿÿÿ 


This is something i am getting. any idea how to handle response in angular code?

Comment: No, generally my recommendation for ajax calls to retrieve a file download is to use a link rather than ajax; then the browser can handle the headers and the datastream itself